# How to run linux and windows container on docker running in windows server 2022?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to run linux and windows container on docker running in windows server 2022?
It is possible with lcow but this is deprecated now.

When running in experimental mode it is working because of lcow, but this is deprecated now.

Comment: This isn't about programming.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To run windows containers on windows server read this, looks like a step-by-step howto: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/

To run linux containers on windows server, well, you could do WSL2 on windows server to have a linux in a minivm and install docker on it, but whats the point, I would not bother with it, just get a linux server for linux containers.